# Populate an empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three columns in my dataset (item_weight, pages and binding).
I have to populate item_weight, having some filters if binding == 'hard' and the no of pages is < 100 and in the end I have to multiple the no of pages with 5  in the item_weight column else binding == 'paper' and the no of pages > 200 than I have to multiple the no of pages with 6.

This is the code that I've used:

```
df_final4['item_weight'] = ''
df_final4.loc[(df_final4(['binding']) == 'hard') & (df_final4((['pages'] < 100))), 'item_weight'] = (5 * (('pages')))
df_final4.loc[(df_final4(['binding']) == 'paper') & (df_final4((['pages'] > 200))), 'item_weight'] = (6 * (('pages')))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected result and what the actual result? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question. And please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

2nd and 3rd rows: substitute

```
df_final4(['binding'])
```

with

```
df_final4['binding']
```

if you use parentheses instead of squared brackets you are calling your dataframe as if it were a function on the ['binding'] argument

Answer (score 0):

Too many `( )` Try:

```
df_final4['item_weight'] = ''
m1 = (df_final4['binding'] == 'hard') & (df_final4['pages'] < 100)
m2 = (df_final4['binding'] == 'paper') & (df_final4['pages'] > 200)
df_final4.loc[m1, 'item_weight'] = 5 * df_final4.loc[m1, 'pages']
df_final4.loc[m2, 'item_weight'] = 6 * df_final4.loc[m2, 'pages']
```

```
>>> df_final4
  binding  pages item_weight
0    hard    271
1    soft    259
2    hard     93         465
3    soft    159
4    hard     26         130
5    hard    226
6    hard     70         350
7   paper    248        1488
8    soft     46
9    hard    145
```

Comment: Not, really. I have to multiple the values of pages that I have with 6, in that column.

Comment: But now, no exception is raised, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, no exceptions are raised,

Comment: It is what you expect?

Comment: The Sample

 binding pages Item_weight

paper    101
hard     204
paper    600
hard     490
paper    150

Comment: Yes, This is what I should get, While I was trying the code I got this TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Try `df_final4['pages'].astype(int)`. Any error? Edit your post with the output of `df_final4.info()` and `df_final4.head(10)`

Comment: I fixed the error, it is working. Thank you a lot and have a nice day ahead! :D